# How to change the default sort order to descending?

Tags: sorting, webmatrix, webgrid

How do I change the `defaultSort` of my `webGrid` to be in the opposite/descending order?  If it were SQL, I'd be adding a `DESC` somewhere.  Here's my working line of code for an Ascending sort:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(dq, rowsPerPage: 50, defaultSort: "UWDate", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid" );
```

It correctly sorts on the `UWDate` column in Ascending order, but I would like it to sort the opposite/descending order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is after your grid initialization:

```
    grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using entity framework then you can use this syntax for ordering to descending order.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Id),canPage: true);
```

This is the design view syntax for the grid print of the model.

```html
@grid.Gethtml()
```

This will print the webgrid in descending order directly in the view of the page MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sort order within the `WebGrid` initialiser by putting a <kbd>space</kbd> followed by `DESC` within the `defaultSort` parameter string.

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "UWDate DESC" ... );
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/post/4962796.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
@{

    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, null, null, 10, true, true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "container-grid2");
}
```